# Here recurrence relation is given and using back substituion what value i will get?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

When n=2^2k for some k >=0, then recurrence relation T(n)=√n T(n/2) + √n, T(1)=1, if we evaluate this what answer will come? Using Back Substition method.

i tried it but i didn't get proper answer. right answer is √n(logn+1).

Comment: Hi. Could you explain what is this "Back Substitution" method so we can help you apply it? It's not a standard term. Also, in the future, for math questions I recommend asking on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ as your question is not directly related to programming, but to computer science.